# Dealing with circular routes in route-finding algorithm

Tags: algorithm, prolog, graph-theory

I have written a program in prolog for finding routes between metro stations. It pretty much works as expected for linear routes `(A -> B -> C -> D)`, but I don't know how to handle the circular ones `(A -> B -> C -> D -> A -> B -> ...)` and so on.

The database:
*stations.pl*

```
train(
    a,
    [
        station2,
        station3,
        station4,
        station10
    ]
).
train(
    b1,
    [   station1,
        station8,
        station3,
        station10,
        station11
    ]
).
train(
    b2,
    [
        station1,
        station11,
        station10,
        station3,
        station8
    ]
).
train(
    c,
    [
        station0,
        station8,
        station21
    ]
).
```

And the program:

*rails.pl*

```
:- include('stations.pl').

% Case: direct route (A) --> (B).
route(A, B, Trains, Acc, R) :-
    train(Train, Stations),
    \+ member(Train, Trains),
    member(A, Stations),
    member(B, Stations),
    append(Acc, [[A, Train, B]], R).

% Case: intermediary station/s (I) between
% departure (A) and destination (B).
route(A, B, Trains, Acc0, R) :-
    train(Train, Stations),
    \+ member(Train, Trains),
    member(A, Stations),
    member(I, Stations),
    A \= I,
    I \= B,
    length(Acc0, L),
    L < 3, % do not find routes where more than 2 changes are needed
    append(Acc0, [[A, Train, I]], Acc1),
    route(I, B, [Train|Trains], Acc1, R).
```

**Linear routes:** `a`, `c`
**Circular route:** `b1`, `b2`

Now let's consider the following case. Showing all the routes from `station2` to `station21`. Results order changed for simplicity.

```
?- route(station2, station21, [], [], R).
R = [[station2, a, station3], [station3, b1, station8], [station8, c, station21]] ;
R = [[station2, a, station3], [station3, b2, station8], [station8, c, station21]] ;
R = [[station2, a, station3], [station3, b1, station1], [station1, b2, station8], [station8, c, station21]] ;
R = [[station2, a, station3], [station3, b2, station1], [station1, b1, station8], [station8, c, station21]] ;
...
...
```

**The problem:**

The problem is, how to make the program aware that `b1` and `b2` share the same route even if the names are different. I want to exclude routes like:

```
station2 (a) station3 -> station3 (b1) station1 -> 
  station1 (b2) station8 -> station8 (c) station21
```

because the distance between `station3` and `station8` can be done on either `b1` or `b2`, no need to change between them.

So basically I want both routes to be treated as one, but have different names depending on the direction of the search. It is not a matter of efficiency at this point, it's about not jumping between `b1` and `b2` on the same route.

EDIT:

- Stopping backtracking after the first result is not an option
- This train route `b1 / b2` is singular among 10+ so I am not necessarily looking for a generic solution, so atom name checking would work (no idea how to do it though).

Comment: Could you please explain `This train route b1 / b2 is singular among 10+ so I am not necessarily looking for a generic solution`

Comment: I haven't look at your code in detail, but just by reading the question I would have a cost of 1 for going from any station to the next station and then add a cost of 1 for changing trains. Thus going the same route but changing trains will have a higher cost. If I understand the question correctly then the answer is just the lowest cost.

Comment: Also doing a breath first search instead of a depth first search will reach the correct answer first.

Comment: @GuyCoder I mean the ```stations.pl``` file is just an example. In reality I have much more routes, but all of them are liniar, except for the ```b1 /b2``` ones. I felt like mentioning this because I would be happy also with the hacky solution based on the 'train' name, not necessarily something general.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is basically a graph search, where the graph is:

```
G=(V,E)
V = Stations
E =  { (u,v) | u,v are stations connected by some train }
```

Your current approach is [Depth First Search (DFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on the graph, starting from source, and going depth first until stuck/finding the solution. One of DFS's known drawbacks is infinite loops.

The classic way to handle this issue is to add a `visited` set, when you first "explore" a node (station), you add it to the `visited` set, and you avoid expanding any nodes that are already in this `visited` set.